# How to avoid resizing (shrink) of SD card and connection refused error in putty for installing raspberry pi

Tags: sd-card, ethernet, putty

I am new with raspberry pi, I want to start the raspberry pi 3,Model B on laptop connected with ethernet cable, but as I want to create a ssh file( with no .txt extension)for the  network error:connection refused in Putty, I removed the SD card and reinserted in card-reader, and it is resized to 1.7GB instead of 14.7GB (16GB SD card). It happens every time I keep the SD card in raspberry pi. 
 So I have formatted everything with cmd\diskpart- clean and made partition primary,I have added the ssh file and tried the putty with the new IP address got in IP scanner. It still says Connection Refused. 
Can you please help me solve this?

Comment: Windows can't see the ext4 partitions on your SDCard so it reports the wrong size. That doesn't mean you've lost any space, it's just been repartitioned by NOOBS or plain Raspbian.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have installed NOOBS.

To set it up you NEED to use a keyboard and monitor.

After setup you can enable ssh in raspi-config or the GUI equivalent.

It can NOT be done on Windows.